# Filtering a RACSequence not working as expected

Tags: core-data, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to refresh a fetched array of objects using ReactiveCocoa, and I'd like to filter out results that have been deleted. I can't quite seem to get things working right — I expect that the `filter` would be passed each `NSManagedObject` in the trackSequence, but instead I see a `_PFBatchFaultingArray` object.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
RACSequence *trackSequence = [documentContextUpdated map:^NSArray *(RACTuple *tuple) {
    return [DWFAbstractTrack MR_findAllSortedBy:DWFAbstractTrackAttributes.order ascending:YES inContext:tuple.second];
}].sequence;

RAC(self, tracks) = [trackSequence filter:^BOOL(NSManagedObject *managedObject) {
    return (NO == [managedObject isDeleted]);
}].signal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `trackSequence` is a `RACSequence` of `NSArray`s, not `NSManagedObject`s. Perhaps you want the `-filter:` in the `-map:`?

```
RAC(self, tracks) = [documentContextUpdated map:^NSArray *(RACTuple *tuple) {
    NSArray *tracks = [DWFAbstractTrack MR_findAllSortedBy:DWFAbstractTrackAttributes.order ascending:YES inContext:tuple.second];
    return [tracks.rac_sequence filter:^BOOL(NSManagedObject *managedObject) {
        return (NO == [managedObject isDeleted]);
    }].array;
}];
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it. For some reason, I didn't even think to return things this way. You're a brain surgeon :)